# date format in my oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to run following select query and its throwing error for date1 as invalid month:

```
SELECT rpad(REPLACE(DECODE(SUBSTR(m.alt_ch_rsp,1,3),'ABM','ATM','SOL','MC ','BRN','FFT','CC '),' ', NULL ),3, ' ')
FROM sp_mosaix m,
  fbl_dis d,
  sp_offer o
WHERE o.offer_id                          = m.offer_id
AND (TRUNC(to_date(m.date1,'yyyy/mm/dd')) < TRUNC(sysdate+10))
```

the date1 is actually a varchar2 data type and NLS_DATE_FORMAT for my database is "DD-MON-RR". I wonder how could I rectify and apply proper date conversion so that it doesn't throw date1 error.

Comment: What does the text in date1 actually look like - example?

Comment: its like 09/11/2014 in the database

Comment: In that case you got the date format wrong...it should be to_date(m.date1,'dd/mm/yyyy')

Comment: As a digression unrelated to your question, it looks like you have a cartesian product (fbl_dis's alias is not joined to anything).

Comment: Hi Patrick, Since code is pretty big, I have just copy pasted the part of code. Having said this fbl_dis is being used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
to_date(m.date1,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

The pattern you use for to_date should match the format of the text - no matter what your NLS_DATE_FORMAT says.

Comment: Thanks Jens, I ll check this

Comment: From Patricks answer I realize that "to_date(m.date1,'mm/dd/yyyy')" might be the correct answer - only you can say.

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting needs to correspond with varchar2 data, 'MM/DD/YYYY'. Since your date1 data follows the format, '09/11/2014', this date model corresponds to 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

```
ALTER session SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR';


SCOTT@dev> WITH m AS
  2    (SELECT '09/11/2014' date1 FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT date1
  5  FROM m
  6  WHERE TRUNC(to_date(m.date1,'MM/DD/YYYY')) < TRUNC(sysdate+10)
  7  /

DATE1
==========
09/11/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue is with your DATA TYPE. A date column MUST always be a DATE data type. There is no reason for it to be defined as VARCHAR2.

It is not only a bad practice, but, down the line, you will face the consequences and side-effects. It is most basic tuning concept in nature, but also very important. And not to forget the performance issues due to implicit data conversion.

As a good reading, you can look at the following article by Ed Stevens, whom I trust as a good DBA : http://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: Yes, we all cringe when we see this.  Often times we deal with the sins of past developers where we are left with supporting something that is less than ideal.

Comment: I agree to you both. Unfortunately this a company database (not to mention poorly designed) and now I am facing this issue.